# javascript is not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, http-status-code-404

Whenever i add **script** tag in **WordPress** and publish/update page, it leads me to the **404 page not found** error.
Simple tags are also giving same error.

```
<script></script>
```

Comment: Are you adding <script></scirpt> tag on page template or in WYSIWYG editor ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your functions.php file:

```
function add_scriptfilter( $string ) {
  global $allowedtags;
  $allowedtags['script'] = array( 'src' => array () );
  return $string;
}
add_filter( 'pre_kses', 'add_scriptfilter' );
```